# Start in path in Task Scheduler ignored

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

I have a powershell program that I add to a task in Task Scheduler.

I set the "Start in (optional)" path to D:\XXX\YYY but when I run the task I see that the current path (retrieved with `Get-Location`) is `C:\Windows\system32` and not the path that I defined in the start in option.

Any suggestions? The Windows version is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Comment: at the beginning of your script execute run `Set-Location D:\XXX\YYY`

Comment: I need to avoid the Set-Location and I want to use relative path in my script. Do you know why the Task Scheduler is ignoring the "Start in" option?

Comment: @Ilaria Manni What is the executed command when scheduled task starts?

Comment: @Manu Program/script: Powershell.exe Add arguments (optional): -ExecutionPolicy Bypass D:\XXX\YYY\script.ps1 Start in (optional): D:\XXX\YYY

Comment: without showing your code/why you need it to be relative I am unable to help.

Comment: @Ilaria Manni Can you try this? Program/script: Powershell.exe Add arguments (optional): -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\XXX\YYY\script.ps1" Start in (optional): D:\XXX\YYY

Comment: Maybe you have spaces in the path hence the arguments are maybe not correctly interpreted. I added `-File` and `"` to pass the arguments properly without misunderstanding

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you assign a trigger other than "One time"? I ask because I ran into the same problem and just noticed the Start in path is ignored when I gave a schedule of every hour for 12 hours. When I give a schedule of "One time", the Start in path is honored. I don't have an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set this command in first line of your script:

Set-Location 'C:\your script PATH'

Answer (score 0):

To use relative paths in your scripts, use `$PSScriptRoot`

For example:

```
$imageDog= "$PSScriptRoot\images\dog.png"
```

To schedule your script through the task scheduler start powershell and in add arguments use:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass D:\XXX\YYY
```

References:

1. [How to: Run PowerShell Scripts from Task Scheduler](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)
2. [Schedule powershell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4iDy.png)